# Which is the primary spacecraft in a conjunction?

Tags: starlink, collision-avoidance, space-track

I ask the question in the title because I cannot find a clear answer.

It seems that in collision avoidance, the primary spacecraft is always more accurately known then the secondary. But I think this is just a consequence of the fact that being the spacecraft a "primary" it is tracked more often, probably because is more important or more easily trackable.

The point is, how to choose which is the primary for instance in the case of two similar objects such as, two starlink satellites.